# How to detect vessel center-line using opencv and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to detect the *center-lines* of a `blood vessel` network using `opencv` and `C++`. I have tried `skeletonization` with limited success. Could anyone point me out in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do:

1. Threshold your image to binary (1 and 0), the pixels on the vessels should have value 1 (black).
2. Erode the image to remove the black pixels on the vessel
3. Repeat Step 2 until no more black pixels can be eroded from the vessel and the remaining image has only the black pixels on the center line.

Here is an example using OpenCV:

http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

Convert to a single channeled image by setting channel of interest and then do edge detect(cvCanny) and then dilute(cvDilate) or Erode(cvErode).